# Themes in Flash Builder and Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, themes, flash-builder

I'm using Themes with Flash Builder. And if I choose a Theme Flash Builder copy the SWC into a folder in my user dir (C:\Users\christenl\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Builder\Themes\myGrand_theme)

When I update my theme file. Flash builder does not copy the new SWC into the folder. So I have to import the theme again or copy the file to the location.

Is there a way to point to the theme project instead so I dont have to manualy copy paste the file every time? 
(The haxed way copy the project into the folder Adobe makes in my user dir, or make the theme project compile the SWC into the theme folder adobe makes.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Flash Catalyst would solve your issue. That's how I do it.